# RV inverter wiring

Tags: wiring, inverter, rv

I would like to install an inverter in my 5th-wheel. I want it wired into the panel so that the trailer will switch between shore/generator/inverter automatically. The problem is, there are a few appliances that I don't want the inverter to power. Is there an easy way to do this using only the main panel, or do I need to set up a sub-panel?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm thinking you're going to need separate circuits to run things separately.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll probably have to set up a sub-panel eventually...